# Choose One Item from Every List, up to N combination, uniform distribution

Tags: python, list, random, combinations

I have 100 lists `[x1..x100]` , each one containing about 10 items. `[x_i_1,...x_i_10]`
I need to generate 80 vectors. Each vector is a production of all the lists, kind of like `itertools.product(*x)`, except 2 things:

(1)
I need every item in each vector to have a uniform distribution. 
for example: 
`[ np.random.choice(xi) for xi in [x1..x100]]` would be good, except for my seconds condition:

(2) 
i can't have repetitions. 
`itertools.product` solves this, but it doesn't meet condition (1).

I need to generate 80 vectors, use them, and re-ask for another 80, and repeat this process until a certain condition is met. 
for EACH vector across all 80-size-batch, i need them to be uniform (condition 1) and non repeating (condition 2)

Creating all permutations and shuffling that list is a great solution for a smaller list, I'm using this batch system because of the HUGE number of possible permutations

Any ideas? 
thx

Comment: To sample from a list without replacement:  make a (shallow) copy of it, `random.shuffle()` the copy, then `.pop()` from the copied shuffled list as many times as you need. Do that on each individual xi list (not on some huge list of every possible permutation).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `[np.random.choice(xi) for xi in [x1..x100]]`. The probability that the same vector will be generated twice in 80 trials is vanishingly small. By the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations) the probability that `n` items chosen independently from a set of `d` items will contain a repeated item chosen is approximately `1 - exp(n*(n-1)/(2*d))`. In your case `n = 80` and `d = 10**100`. The resulting probability is zero to a ridiculously large number of decimal places (the estimate implies that the probability begins 0.000 ... with approximately 1.37 x 10^97 zeros after the decimal point). Forget 80. You could generate 80 trillion such vectors and still have a vanishingly small probability of generating the same vector twice.